# PHP/Laravel repository pattern, proper logic in creating "complex" objects

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

Going around with the logic of manipulating "complex" objects using the repository pattern, going back and forth...
Btw, i'm using Laravel framework.

Ok, i have these tables in the database:

- users
- companies
- company_translations
- company_contacts
- company_files

relations:
- users has a one-one polymorphic with companies (i have more types of users, like administrators and clients)
- companies has a one-many with company_translations (some attributes of the company can be translated into multiple languages)
- companies has a one-many with company_contacts
- companies has a one-many with company_files

I have a CompanyController and a CompanyRepository. I'm trying to put all the logic of creating
the Company in the CompanyRepository, and not making use of a repo for the others parts of the company (contacts, files, translations).

So, for example, when an administrator is creating a company, the controller receives the info from (there's also a form request responsible for validating the inputs, typical rules) a form with all the data
regarding a company (core, translations, file, contacts), then it will pass that data to the repo function, like:

```
$company = $this->companyRepository->create($data);
```

My issue is in that function, how do i struture/validate the data passed to the funcion? It has to create an entry in the table companies, one for the user, 1 or more for the translations, 1 or more for the contacts, 0 or more for the files.

For example, the inputs coming from the request regarding the translations are organized like:

```
companyDescription['en']
companyDescription['es']
companyDescription['pt']
etc
```

The repo shouldnt supposed to know it's structure, right? Do i do it inside the controller, for example:

```
$userData = [
  'email'    => $request->input('email'),
  'password' => $request->input('password'),
  etc
];

$companyData = [
  'company_name' => $request->input('companyName'),
  'company_slug' => $request->input('companySlug'),
  etc 
];
```

and then pass these variables to the repo function? Also some field arent required, so not all of the data is necessary, ie, the file is not mandatory.
How do i chain all the necessary steps? 
Or do i approach this in a totally different way?

Getting this logic right is getting in my nerves... all solutions are welcome.

Hope i was clear +/- in explaing what i have and what the problem is. Oh and i want to stick with the Repository Pattern ;)

Comment: Go with slim controllers, fat models. You controller should not validate any business data that it handles, that's the model's job(well, in this context anyway). So the validation should be handled in the repository. Specific validation should be handled in the whatever repo you need, general validation can be handled by the parent repo.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but i want to stick with the repo pattern.

Comment: I suppose this is a question for the software engineering stack.

Comment: @schellingerht when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @Andrew sry, i miss read you. You refered using the repo for the validation, yes. Im doing +/- a validation in the repo, besides the form request, the code is just wrong, that's why i wanted help in how to chain the necessary steps and structering.